# Converting json object to typescript interface causing error in the mock object while unit testing in Angular 11

Tags: json, angular, typescript, unit-testing, interface

I am receiving a json response in an Angular 11 app and I have created an interface corresponding to that json object. The json object is

```
{
  "division": {
      "uid": "f5a10d90-60d6-4937-b917-1d809bd180b4",
      "name": "Sales Division",
      "title": "Sales",
      "type": "Form",
      "formFields": [
          {
              "id": 1,
              "name": "firstName",
              "label": "First Name",
              "value": "John"
          },
          {
              "id": 2,
              "name": "lastName",
              "label": "Last Name",
              "value": "Smith"
          }
      ]
   }
}
```

The typescript interface I created for this json object is

```
export interface FormField {
   id: number;
   name: string;
   label: string;
   value: string;
}

export interface Division {
   uid: string;
   name: string;
   title: string;
   type: string;
   formFields: FormField[];
}

export interface Division {
   division: Division;
}
```

I am using a service **division.sevice.ts** to fetch the above json response from API and everything works fine. I am trying to write unit tests for the this service in the **division.service.spec.ts** file. I created a **mockDivisionObj** inside this file for testing purpose which is shown below.

```
mockDivisionObj = {
  "division": {
      "uid": "f5a10d90-60d6-4937-b917-1d809bd180b4",
      "name": "Sales Division",
      "title": "Sales",
      "type": "Form",
      "formFields": [
          {
              "id": 1,
              "name": "firstName",
              "label": "First Name",
              "value": "John"
          },
          {
              "id": 2,
              "name": "lastName",
              "label": "Last Name",
              "value": "Smith"
          }
      ]
  }
}
```

An error is shown which says

```
Property 'division' is missing in type '{ uid: string; name: string; title: string; type: 
string; formFields: { id: number; name: string; label: string; value: string; }[]; }' but 
required in type 'Division'.
```

I think the way I created the interface may be wrong but I couldn't figure out what exactly is causing the issue. Please help me out with this.

Comment: You have two interfaces named division?

Comment: Yes but when I change the last declared interface name to 'AppDivision', then inside my actual component I get the error 
Property 'division' is missing in type 'Division' but required in type 'AppDivision'

Comment: I don't think this code will even compile as it isn't possible to define two types with the same name. You will need to address that first.

Comment: The code still compiles even if we have two interfaces with same name in one file as I got the main functionality working without issues. But to fix the above issue I changed the name of one interface to 'AppDivision' and fixed the error in component I mentioned above.

Comment: @suvenk You can check my answer. I think you do not require the extra interface  called `AppDivision`. Best wishes :-)

Answer (score 1):

I was able to fix the issue by changing the name of one of the interfaces in the file to 'AppDivision' as shown below.

```
export interface FormField {
   id: number;
   name: string;
   label: string;
   value: string;
}

export interface Division {
   uid: string;
   name: string;
   title: string;
   type: string;
   formFields: FormField[];
}

export interface AppDivision {
   division: Division;
}
```

The same name for two interfaces caused the error in the unit test mock object.

Comment: You can check my answer. I think you do not require the extra interface  called `AppDivision`. Best wishes :-)

Answer (score 0):

Your code is fine.To solve this error you can try the code below =>

```
  this.division = this.mockDivisionObj.division as Division;
```

**Check the Link:** [StackBlitz Demo link](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-convert-json-to-objects-1nyabl?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts).